# In Numbers.app, Is there any function to identify if another cell is a formula, or contains a specific function?

Tags: numbers, iwork

I have a cell in a row that is either a directly entered number, or a SUM() of some other cells. Is there any function I can use in a different cell to know if the value in the former cell was directly entered or the result of a formula?

Comment: If the cells summed are consistent, you could some them somewhere else (perhaps hidden or otherwise out of view) then you could compare the values.

Comment: I am unaware of any such function even with Excel.  Are you looking for conditional formatting based on a particular cell?

Comment: Summed cells are not consistent. Not conditionally formatting; just looking to do a different formula in ANOTHER cell based on whether the first cell is a formula vs. number.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how do you plan on using this feature? Maybe there's another method.